# Conditional datetime column filling in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a DateTime column in pandas dataframe and I want to create a new column which conditionally fills based on the datetime_column value.

Example of my dataframe:

```
datetime_column
2018-09-19 17:00:03
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-20 07:00:30
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-21 13:00:30
NaT
NaT
NaT
Nat
2018-09-22 20:00:30
NaT
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-22 04:00:30
```

If the value of datetime_column is in between the time 00:00:00 and 09:00:00, it should fill it with the previous value else it should fill in with the same value as the datetime_column value

Expected dataframe:

```
datetime_column         datetime_column_x
2018-09-19 17:00:03     2018-09-19 17:00:03
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-20 07:00:30     2018-09-19 17:00:03
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-21 13:00:30     2018-09-21 13:00:30
NaT 
NaT
NaT
Nat
2018-09-22 20:00:30     2018-09-22 20:00:30
NaT
NaT
NaT
NaT
2018-09-22 04:00:30     2018-09-22 20:00:30
```

*Tried code:*

```
start_time : '00:00:00'
end_time :   '12:00:00'
df['datetime_column_x'] = np.where((df['datetime'] >= start_time & 
                          df['datetime']<= end_time), df['datetime']-1, 
                          df['datetime'])
```

But the above code gives me an error:

`TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using `shift` here

```
s=df['datetime_column'].ffill()
df['datetime_column_x']=np.where(df.datetime_column.dt.hour.between(0,9),s.shift(),df['datetime_column'])
df
Out[441]: 
       datetime_column   datetime_column_x
0  2018-09-19 17:00:03 2018-09-19 17:00:03
1                  NaT                 NaT
2                  NaT                 NaT
3                  NaT                 NaT
4  2018-09-20 07:00:30 2018-09-19 17:00:03
5                  NaT                 NaT
6                  NaT                 NaT
7                  NaT                 NaT
8  2018-09-21 13:00:30 2018-09-21 13:00:30
9                  NaT                 NaT
10                 NaT                 NaT
11                 NaT                 NaT
12                 NaT                 NaT
13 2018-09-22 20:00:30 2018-09-22 20:00:30
14                 NaT                 NaT
15                 NaT                 NaT
16                 NaT                 NaT
17                 NaT                 NaT
18 2018-09-22 04:00:30 2018-09-22 20:00:30
```

Comment: @akashbachu I do not think so , let me modify it , I try to match with your output , will update within 5mins , sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Wen-Ben's answer is comprehensive - but make sure your dates are in the right format to compare to python's `datetime` library. This won't work with numpy `datetime64` objects.

Convert your the dates to `datetime` or pandas `Timestamp` objects:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'datetime'])
# or
df['datetime'] = df.loc[:, 'datetime'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Then do as Wen-Ben says, comparing the `datetime.time` attributes.